# Quick one (easy I hope!) about scope with function objects in Javascript...ode>

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, scope

Good evening fellow coders, and thank you in advance for any help/attention.

This is about JavaScript Function objects when declared using a statement (not expression) and adding properties to them.

IF this works: (which it does!)

```
function Test(){
     alert( Test.Data );
}

// Define a property on the method.
Test.Data = "Method property";

// Execute the method.
Test();
```

then why does this not work?

```
function Test(){
  var Data = "Method property";
  alert( Test.Data );
}

// Execute the method.
Test();
```

or even this?

```
function Test(){
  Data : "Method property";
  alert( Test.Data );
}

// Execute the method.
Test();
```

In english: what I don't understand is why you can set a property in the function object from outside but not from inside... I am thinking it is something to do with context and how the function object doesn't exist, or a reference to it is not in scope at the point I am trying to set the internal property...it would be nice if someone can confirm/deny/clarify for me.

Thank you.

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* set a property on a function object from within it. You do it exactly how you do it from outside:

```
function Test() {
    Test.Data = "Method property";
    alert(Test.Data);
}
```

Your question has nothing to with scope and everything to do with understanding the syntax for setting object properties vs. the syntax for creating local variables.

> then why does this not work?
>
> ```
> function Test(){
>   var Data = "Method property";
>   alert( Test.Data );
> }
> ```

Because `Data` in this case is simply a local variable, not a property on the function, so `Test.Data` is `undefined`.

> or even this?
>
> ```
> function Test(){
>   Data : "Method property";
>   alert( Test.Data );
> }
> ```

Because `Data` in this case is simply [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Again, this has no relationship with any properties set on `Test`.

Comment: +1 For being both the first to post and the first to get it right. (I've since fixed my answer with regard to the label, thanks to you, so I guess I'm second on both counts though your original post only beat me by ten seconds or so...)

Comment: Thanks a million - damn! syntax eh? :-)

Comment: assuming 
`code` 


    function Test(){
        this.Data = "Method property";
        alert( Test.Data );
    }
doesn't work b/cos "this" points to, um, in this case, global object

Comment: @user1181366 - Yes, unless you called it like this (among other ways) -- `new Test()` -- in which case `this` inside the function refers to the new object being created. Note that you'd then be setting a property on an *instance* of `Test` and not on `Test` itself.

Comment: yes. thanks, basically was trying to establish EXACTLY what "NEW" does. fascinating language... confusing, but fascinating. :-)

Comment: this helped. from Javascript, the definitive guide - 
4.6.2. Local Variables: The Call Object::
If global variables are properties of the special global object, then what are local variables? They too are properties of an object. This object is known as the call object. The call object has a shorter life span than the global object, but it serves the same purpose. While the body of a function is executing, the function arguments and local variables are stored as properties of this call object.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a scope issue, it's about the difference between object properties and (local) variables.

1. The first syntax is setting a property on your function because functions are objects and can have properties set just like any object can.
2. The second syntax creates a local variable that is accessible directly by name within the function, but it is not an object property so can't be accessed with the object property `objectname.propertyname` syntax. Try `alert(Data);` and it will display the value of the local variable. Or say `Test.Data = "something";` *inside* the function and that will work too.
3. The third syntax seems like you were trying to use the `propertyname : value` syntax that works within object literals, except you don't have an object literal so really that it is actually the label syntax. `Data :` becomes a label, and then `"Method property";` is a statement that doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is wrong: "The third syntax is just not valid JS." It's a label.

Comment: @lwburk - Thanks. I'm kicking myself because I _knew_ that. Will fix.

Comment: I'll tell you a dirty little secret. I started to say it was illegal in my answer, too, but edited once I realized my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the first two items are doing different things, and the third isn't setting a value - it just sets up an unused label.

Item 1 creates a function, which is a type of object, and then assigns a value to a property named "Data" on that object. Then it calls the function, and the function looks at the property.

Item 2 creates a function, and within the scope of execution of that function, defines a variable. It then looks on the object representing that function for a property named "Data", and fails to find it.

Comment: Wrong: "and the third isn't valid javascript." It's a label.

Comment: @lwburk - Javascript has gotos!?!

Comment: No, you label loops and refer to those labels using `break` or `continue` (e.g. to break out of an outer loop from an inner one).

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects in javascript, and act like any other object.  `Test.Data = "foo"` just adds a variable `Data` to the `Test` object, and assigns the value to `"foo"`.  The function itself isn't changed.

Also, declaring variables inside a function scope does not add those variables to the function object.  They're only accessible from within the function using the name they were declared with.

I believe this will do essentially what you are trying to do in version 2:

```
function Test() {
  this.Data = "Method Property";
  alert(this.Data); // Does what you expect
}
var test = new Test();
alert(test.Data); // alerts what you expect
```